# How to have a bar hover under my links

Tags: html, css

I am making a cool looking navigation bar using css and I want a bar to appear under my links when I hover over them. Basically I need the background color of one box to change when I hover over a different one.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="links">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="link1"></td><a href="Index.html">Calvin and Hobbes</a></td>
            <td class="link2"><a href="Index.html">Garfield</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hoverbar">
            <td class="link1hover"></td>
            <td class="link2hover"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Here is my Css:

```
.links {
    float:right;
    font-size:200%;
}

#navbar table{
    margin-top:30px;
    border-spacing:40px 0px;
}

#navbar td {
line-height:30px;
}

.hoverbar {
    height:5px;
}

.link1:hover + .link1hover {
    background-color:#FF5C00;
}

.link2:hover + .link2hover {
    background-color:#FF5C00;
}

a:link {color:black; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
a:visited {color:black; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:#FF5C00; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
a:active {color:#FF5C00; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current set up, these selectors don't work

```
.link1:hover + .link1hover {
  background-color:#FF5C00;
}
```

Because `.link1hover` is not directly next to `.link1` because they both have different parents. So to get this to work with your structure you would need javascript or rearrange your code like this:

```css
.links {
  float: right;
  font-size: 200%;
}

.link1hover, .link2hover {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

.link1:hover ~ .link1hover {
  background-color: #FF5C00;
}

.link2:hover ~ .link2hover {
  background-color: #FF5C00;
}

a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:hover {
  color: #FF5C00;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:active {
  color: #FF5C00;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="links">
    <div class="link1"><a href="Index.html">Calvin and Hobbes</a></div>
    <div class="link2"><a href="Index.html">Garfield</a></div>
    <div class="link1hover"></div>
    <div class="link2hover"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. So I rearranged my code so the table is replaced with div boxes and now it seems to work. So do I always replace the + with a ~

Comment: `+` means a direct sibling. so if you use `.link1:hover + div` that would target the div next to it (`.link2`) Because you are targeting elements that aren't directly next to it then you need the general sibling selector `~`

Answer (score 0):

try this code.this will help you to build your navigation bar.just copy ,paste and try it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome !</title>

<style type="text/css">

body{
    margin:0;
  padding: :0;

}
.navigation{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

ul li:hover{
  background-color: white;

}

ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;


}

ul li a:hover{
  color:orange;
}

</style>


 <body>

  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Calvin and Hobbes</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Garfield</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


 </body>
</html>
```